# How to properly separate production and mockup class

Tags: java

I have GPS reader class which delivers coordinates from a GPS receiver. This works on machines with real receivers obviously. Now I created a mockup class which randomly gives me coordinates so I can start my application and see if everything works without having to deploy it to another machine.

Now this is the structure:

```
class AbstractGPSReader {
}

class RealGPSReader extends AbstractGPSReader {
}

class FakeGPSReader extends AbstractGPSReader {
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    private AbstractGPSReader gpsReader = new RealGPSReader();
}
```

To be able to test the application I have to replace

```
new RealGPSReader()
```

with

```
new FakeGPSReader()
```

Is there a more elegant way? 
Can I prevent someone from using this class in production?

Comment: You can mock with `Mockito` [http://site.mockito.org/](http://site.mockito.org/). It is very easy and compatible with Junit tests

Comment: I want to test it myself. I think this is for unit tests, isn't it?

Comment: If you are using spring you could instantiate and autowire your classes based on profiles.

Comment: Yes I am using spring (but new to it). I'll take a look at. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It's quite simple: classes should be given instances of their dependencies rather than creating the dependencies themselves.

For example:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    private final AbstractGPSReader gpsReader = new RealGPSReader();
}
```

Becomes:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    private final AbstractGPSReader gpsReader;
    public SomeOtherClass(AbstractGPSReader gpsReader) {
        this.gpsReader = gpsReader;
    }
}
```

The advantage of this is that now `SomeOtherClass` is only coupled to `AbstractGPSReader`, whereas before it was coupled to `AbstractGPSReader` and `RealGPSReader`.

This is a huge benefit when writing unit-tests because now the class can be used by a test-suite unmodified:

```
void testSomeOtherClass() {
    SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(new FakeGPSReader());
    someOtherClass.someMethod(); 
    // etc... 
}
```

There are frameworks that can help you automated the injection of dependencies, but I would suggest holding off on those to maintain code simplicity.

---

As an aside, you should try to build your API around interfaces rather than abstract classes.

Comment: This seems reasonable, thanks! I can't use an interface but I tried :) It's old code I want to improve.